# JavaFX in Swing - Migration & Look and feel

Tags: swing, javafx, look-and-feel

Oracle makes the migration from Swing to JavaFX possible by letting us mix both architectures. The problem though is that an application with both architectures mixed together looks like a rag rug and is unacceptable.

Is there a way to adapt the look and feel of swing to the JavaFX look and feel without having to write yet another Swing LAF?

Having messed around long enough with Swing's platform-dependent look and feels, I rather prefer the application looks the same on all platforms, even on linux. That's why I prefer to change Swing, not JavaFX.

Thank you very much.

Comment: wouldnt it look terrible to use same look and feel on a mac though, mac users are very fussy about this.